# Automatically update the time and date shapefile

Tags: arcmap

How can I automatically update the time and date problem in the attributes of the shapefile instead of writing the time manually as the time always appears at 12:00 am?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please be sure to provide a complete description of what you are attempting.  Screenshots are often a good way to provide additional information (except for code and errors, which need to have a text component for legibility and indexing).

Answer (score 1):

The Datetime field in shapefiles do not record time, they only record the date, so all dates in a shapefile table displays as 12:00 am (or 00:00:00).

> However, for coverages and shapefiles, the time portion is truncated from the
>   datetime value. For example, the datetime 2002-08-20 12:00:00 PM is
>   stored in a coverage or shapefile as 2002-08-20.

See [Fundamentals of date fields](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm)